# Egyptian numerals (fractions)

Tags: xetex, numbering

I'm trying to insert some roman and greek numerals in a beamer presentation compliled with XeLaTex (the choice is determined from the fact that I have also to insert some Egyptian, Babylonian and Maya numerals)

I have a question:
Can egyptian fractions and the "plus and minus signs" be rendered in XeLatex?
see e.g. [Egyptian numerals in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_numerals) if yes, how?

I think It will be useful to reopen the question since I suppose @yasper code has a little problem. It render correctly every number except 1,000,000 that is rendered as 1,100,000. Since the answer by @yasper was great I think this little bug worth to be corrected and the answed to be reopened.

I'm sorry but I'm not able to correct the bug by myself since the code is a bit too complex to understand for me.

Thank you a lot in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, I probably misread your question, so it does not exactly answer it. However as to how to insert Egyptian hieroglyphs, you can use `\char"00000` and replace `00000` by the relevant Unicode codepoint. You can stack hieroglyphs using `\shortstack` for example.

So, in order to typeset the hieroglyph for negative numbers, you can type `\char"130BB`. For one fourth, you could write `\shortstack{ \char"1308B \\ \char"133FD }`. Of course, you would need to have a font installed that supports Egyptian hieroglyphs.

---

The following code provides a macro that converts intergers (positive and negative as well as zero) to the equivalent in Egyptian hieroglyphs up to 9,999,999.

Since you are interested in fractions, this can be easily extended to support fractions (only unit fractions are supported by the Egyptian hieroglyphic writing system, there are special glyphs for ⅔ and ¾ though):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans Egyptian Hieroglyphs}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l_egyptiannumeral_tempa_int
\int_new:N \l_egyptiannumeral_tempb_int
\int_new:N \l_egyptiannumeral_currentpower_int
\seq_new:N \l_egyptiannumeral_egyptiandigits_seq

\NewDocumentCommand { \egyptiannumeral } { m } {
    \int_set:Nn \l_egyptiannumeral_tempa_int { #1 }
    \int_compare:nNnT { \int_use:N \l_egyptiannumeral_tempa_int } = { 0 } { 
        \char"13124
    }
    \int_compare:nNnT { \int_use:N \l_egyptiannumeral_tempa_int } < { 0 } { 
        \char"130BB
        \int_set:Nn \l_egyptiannumeral_tempa_int { 
            #1 * -1
        }
    }
    \seq_clear:N \l_egyptiannumeral_egyptiandigits_seq
    \int_set:Nn \l_egyptiannumeral_currentpower_int { 0 }
    \int_do_until:nn { \l_egyptiannumeral_tempa_int <= 0 } {
        \int_set:Nn \l_egyptiannumeral_tempb_int { \int_mod:nn { \l_egyptiannumeral_tempa_int } { 10 } }
        \int_sub:Nn \l_egyptiannumeral_tempa_int { \l_egyptiannumeral_tempb_int } 
        \int_set:Nn \l_egyptiannumeral_tempa_int { \int_div_truncate:nn \l_egyptiannumeral_tempa_int { 10 } }
        \seq_put_left:Nx \l_egyptiannumeral_egyptiandigits_seq { \int_use:N \l_egyptiannumeral_tempb_int } 
        \int_incr:N \l_egyptiannumeral_currentpower_int
    }
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_egyptiannumeral_egyptiandigits_seq {
        \int_case:nn { \l_egyptiannumeral_currentpower_int } {
            { 1 } {
                \str_case:nn { ##1 } {
                    { 0 } {  }
                    { 1 } { \char"133FA }
                    { 2 } { \char"133FB }
                    { 3 } { \char"133FC }
                    { 4 } { \char"133FD }
                    { 5 } { \char"133FE }
                    { 6 } { \char"133FF }
                    { 7 } { \char"13400 }
                    { 8 } { \char"13401 }
                    { 9 } { \char"13402 }
                }
            }
            { 2 } {
                \str_case:nn { ##1 } {
                    { 0 } {  }
                    { 1 } { \char"13386 }
                    { 2 } { \char"13387 }
                    { 3 } { \char"13388 }
                    { 4 } { \char"13389 }
                    { 5 } { \char"1338A }
                    { 6 } { \char"1338B }
                    { 7 } { \char"1338C }
                    { 8 } { \char"1338D }
                    { 9 } { \char"1338E }
                }
            }
            { 3 } {
                \str_case:nn { ##1 } {
                    { 0 } {  }
                    { 1 } { \char"13362 }
                    { 2 } { \char"13363 }
                    { 3 } { \char"13364 }
                    { 4 } { \char"13365 }
                    { 5 } { \char"13366 }
                    { 6 } { \char"13367 }
                    { 7 } { \char"13368 }
                    { 8 } { \char"13369 }
                    { 9 } { \char"1336A }
                }
            }
            { 4 } {
                \str_case:nn { ##1 } {
                    { 0 } {  }
                    { 1 } { \char"131BC }
                    { 2 } { \char"131BD }
                    { 3 } { \char"131BE }
                    { 4 } { \char"131BF }
                    { 5 } { \char"131C0 }
                    { 6 } { \char"131C1 }
                    { 7 } { \char"131C2 }
                    { 8 } { \char"131C3 }
                    { 9 } { \char"131C4 }
                }
            }
            { 5 } {
                \str_case:nn { ##1 } {
                    { 0 } {  }
                    { 1 } { \char"130AD }
                    { 2 } { \char"130AE }
                    { 3 } { \char"130AF }
                    { 4 } { \char"130B0 }
                    { 5 } { \char"130B1 }
                    { 6 } { \char"130B2 }
                    { 7 } { \char"130B3 }
                    { 8 } { \char"130B4 }
                    { 9 } { \char"130B5 }
                }
            }
            { 6 } {
                \int_set:Nn \l_egyptiannumeral_tempa_int { ##1 } 
                \int_until_do:nn { \l_egyptiannumeral_tempa_int <= 0 } {
                    \char"13190
                    \int_decr:N \l_egyptiannumeral_tempa_int
                }
            }
            { 7 } {
                \int_set:Nn \l_egyptiannumeral_tempa_int { ##1 } 
                \int_until_do:nn { \l_egyptiannumeral_tempa_int <= 0 } {
                    \char"13068
                    \int_decr:N \l_egyptiannumeral_tempa_int
                }
            }
        }
        \int_decr:N \l_egyptiannumeral_currentpower_int
    }
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \egyptianfractiontwothirds } { } { \char"1308C }

\NewDocumentCommand { \egyptianfractionthreefourths } { } { \char"1308D }

\NewDocumentCommand { \egyptianfraction } { m } {
    \int_set:Nn \l_egyptiannumeral_tempa_int { #1 }
    \int_compare:nNnTF { \int_use:N \l_egyptiannumeral_tempa_int } = { 2 } { 
        \char"1341E
    } {
        \shortstack {
            \char"1308B \\
            \egyptiannumeral { #1 }
        }
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\egyptiannumeral{0}

\egyptiannumeral{2020}

\egyptiannumeral{1234567}

\egyptiannumeral{-145}

\bigskip

\egyptianfraction{2} \quad \egyptianfraction{3} \quad \egyptianfraction{12}

\egyptianfractiontwothirds

\egyptianfractionthreefourths

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Since I'm not so skilled with latex I have another question. To insert Babylonian numerals I have to put a font (SantakkuM) in the folder in which I have my .tex file. Since I have many different fonts, how can I do the same for the Noto Sans Egyptian Hieroglyphs font? I think I can not specify a single font for all the document. Thank you a lot in advance.

Comment: @Mathland You can place the font where you placed the other fonts. Also, you can create custom font families to switch between. See the [`fontspec` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf).

Comment: How can I proceed If I want to add a few single charaters from your Noto Sans Egyptian Hieroglyphs font? There is not clear from the above manual. Thanks

Comment: @Mathland Define a font family using `\newfontfamily{\egypfont}{Noto Sans Egyptian Hieroglyphs}` and then use it like this: `ABC {\egypfont\char"1308D} DEF`.

Comment: I tried and it says font not found when I try to compile. I put the NotoSansEgyptianHieroglyphs-Regular.ttf file in the working folder

Comment: @Mathland Then try `\newfontfamily{\egyp}{NotoSansEgyptianHieroglyphs-Regular.ttf}`.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Finally it works. A Last question how to find the list of unicode codes for each charachter this font?

Comment: @Mathland As far as I know, Noto Sans Egyptian Hieroglyphs covers the full [Unicode Block "Egyptian Hieroglyphs"](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U13000.pdf) about which you can find information [on the internet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_Hieroglyphs_(Unicode_block)) quite easily. As I said, you can just type the hexadecimal Unicode codepoint using `\char"00000`.

Comment: I think your code has a little problem. It render correctly every number except 1,000,000 that is rendered as 1,100,000. 

I'm sorry but I'm not able to correct the bug by myself since the code is a bit too complex to understand for me.

Comment: @Mathland Thanks: Fixed

Comment: Now it works perfectly! Thank you a lot!